# Expo app stops connecting to the deployed server URL

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, amazon-ec2, expo

i have an app built with expo, it works fine and was deployed, the server side was hosted on aws using the ec2 instance. however 2 days ago i tried accessing the app and for some reason it wasn't working so i checked the server side using the web as it is a custom domain, it worked fine, i tried checking if it will work on postman and it worked fine, no changes were made to the client or server side code it just stopped working (the expo app won't make api calls to the hosted server). the only thing i know i did was i terminated an Elastic Ip address that i set up when creating the instance, but even after the termination the app still worked fine for days before it stopped, i don't know what information to add or what to do or how to go about it, i would really appreciate any help.

i have tried checking my code but it works fine if i use localhost so it has to do with the domain, the domain however is accessible through the web and works fine in post man.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.